# How to set struct member dynamically

Tags: go

Now I'm working on GO RPC, I'm using gRPC+Protobuf. And I follow [openconfig](https://github.com/openconfig/public)'s data struct, so I could NOT redesign.

I need to fill protobuf struct and Marshal it and send it out, and then client will Unmarshal it and read datas.

My protobuf file(xxx.pb.go) is complicated, for example, just like this:

```
type ObjBase struct {
    a *ObjChildAlice,
    b *ObjChildBob,
    ... // there are many variables like ObjChildCheer, ObjChildDog ...
}

type ObjChildAlice struct {
    child *ObjChildChild,
}

type ObjChildBob struct {
    child *ObjChildChild,
}

// there are many types like ObjChildCheer, ObjChildDog ...

type ObjChildChild {
    int i,
}
```

In server side, I need to fill `ObjBase` and send it out, this is my task:

```
// Code 1
func () {
    init ob with ObjBase

    if DataBase has Alice {
        fill ob.a with ObjChildAlice
    }
    if DataBase has Bob {
        fill ob.a with ObjChildBob
    }
    // there are many if..else.. DataBase has Cheer...
    return ob
}
```

So I code like this first:

```
// Code 2
func () {
    ob := new(ObjBase)
    oba := new(ObjChildAlice)
    obb := new(ObjChildBob)
    if DataBase has Alice {
        ob.a = oba
    }
    if DataBase has Bob {
        ob.b = obb
    }
    ...
    return ob
}
```

But this code could NOT work, as I check member of ob.a and ob.b are all zero.

So I change like this:

```
// Code 3
func () {
    if DataBase has Alice && DataBase has Bob {
        ob := &ObjBase{
            a: &ObjChildAlice{},
            b: &ObjChildBob{},
        }
    } else if DataBase has Alice && NOT DataBase has Bob {
        ob := &ObjBase{
            a: &ObjChildAlice{},
        }
    } else if ...
    return ob
}
```

This works. But in database, there are kinds of variables like Alice, Bob, Cheer, Dog ... It's impossible to use if..else.. to do this work.

So I have questions:

1. Why ob'member in Code2 is zero?
2. is there any way to set Go struct's member object dynamically?

Comment: There's no difference between `new(T)` and `&T{}`. It's hard to tell you what's wrong with pseudo code. Make a small *working* example.

Comment: To quote a wise man: Do not try to emulate inheritance in Go. It will hurt.

Comment: `new` has a few valid use-cases, but 99% of the time, it's better to create a literal (`ob := &ObjBase{}`).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this doc which talks the Go generated code for protobufs. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated

You should be able to set a protobuf message field in the generated code by directly accessing the corresponding member field (which is exported).